# Custom Http in angular 2

Tags: angular2-services

I have made a custom http service named customHttp which is fillowing:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class customHttp extends Http {
    tokenexpired: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {

        super(backend, options);
        console.log('In constructor');
        let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token'); // your custom token getter function here
        options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        this.tokenexpired.next(false);
        console.log('token is');
        console.log(this.tokenexpired);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        console.log('In service');
        let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
        if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
            if (!options) {
                // let's make option object
                options = {headers: new Headers()};
            }
            options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        } else {
            // we have to add the token to the url object
            url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        }
        return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
    }

    post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        console.log('Before the request...');
        return super.post(url, body, options)
            .catch((err: any): any => {
                if (err.status === 400 || err.status === 422) {
                    //FIRE NOTIFICATION IN THIS POINT FOR EXAMPLE.
                    return Observable.throw(err);
                } else {


                }
            })
            .finally(() => {
                console.log('After the request...');
            });
    }
    private catchAuthError(self: customHttp) {
        // we have to pass HttpService's own instance here as `self`
        return (res: Response) => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
                // if not authenticated
                console.log(res);
                this.deletetoken();
            }
            return Observable.throw(res);
        };
    }

    private deletetoken() {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        this.tokenexpired.next(true);
    }
}
```

I have injected this customHttp service in my authservice. This is my authservices constructor:

```
constructor(private http: customHttp) {
        this.number = this.generate();
    }
```

And I am making an http call in following way:

```
register(data: any): Promise<Response> {
        let datatosend = JSON.stringify({
            email: data.email,
            password: '12345',
            user: {cnic: data.cnic, phone: this.number}
        });
        return this.http
            .post(authUrls.register,datatosend , {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                this._profileChange(response);
                this._serrviceLogin();
                return response;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Now according to my understanding my customHttp service should intercept this http call and messege "console.log('Before the request...')" and "console.log('After the request...');" should be printed on console. But it is not happening. Anyone please guide me where is the mistake. Thanks!

**Update**

Providers array in my app.module.ts looks like following!

```
providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGaurd,
    FileuploadService,
    DocumentService,
      {
          provide: customHttp,
          useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
              return new customHttp(backend, options);
          },
          deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
      },
    /*for mockbackend*/
    fakeBackendProvider,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions
  ],
```

Comment: @Adones Pitogo can you please look into this!